# Arraylist elements being repeated after the last index

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-gridview

The problems I am facing are -

1.I have a Custom Grid View. The Adapter for the view inflates items for only five elements but while displaying the list repeats itself after the last index.

For example if there are only 5 elements in the adapter, while displaying it becomes 10 or 15 and then when I click on any item it shows outOfBoundException.

2.When the sub button is clicked,it should decrease the number of items by one. Sometimes, it just doesn't. I cannot figure out the reason. Add button works perfectly.

```
public class MyAdaptertwo extends BaseAdapter
{
public static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
 int j;
int k=0;
public static int no[]=new int[5];
public static int co[]=new int[5];
public static int cos[]={1,2,3,4,5};


public static List<list> rowitems = new ArrayList<list>();
static int size=0;


public MyAdaptertwo(Context context)
{
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);


    items.add(new Item("S", R.drawable.s,"1",R.drawable.v));
    items.add(new Item("F", R.drawable.t,"2",R.drawable.v));
    items.add(new Item("C",R.drawable.c,"3",R.drawable.n));
    items.add(new Item("P", R.drawable.i,"4",R.drawable.v));
    items.add(new Item("P", R.drawable.p,"5",R.drawable.n));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i)
{
    j=i;
    return items.get(i);
}
public void setCost(int i,String a)
{
    items.get(i).cost=a;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i)
{
    return items.get(i).colorId;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{

    View v = view;
    ImageView picture;
    ImageView vn;
    TextView name;
    TextView costs;

    if(v == null)
    {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, viewGroup, false);
        v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
        v.setTag(R.id.vnon, v.findViewById(R.id.vnon));
        v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        v.setTag(R.id.cost,v.findViewById(R.id.cost));
    }

    picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
    vn=(ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.vnon);
    name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);
    costs=(TextView)v.getTag(R.id.cost);

    Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

    picture.setImageResource(item.colorId);
    name.setText(item.name);
    costs.setText(item.cost);
    vn.setImageResource(item.vnId);
      Button add=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.add);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (size == 0) {
                Log.e("first j-1",Integer.toString(j-1));
                no[j - 1] = no[j - 1] + 1;
                Log.e("first no[j-1]",Integer.toString(no[j-1]));
                list item = new list(items.get(j - 1).colorId, items.get(j - 1).name, Integer.toString(co[j-1]), Integer.toString(no[j - 1]));
                rowitems.add(item);

                Log.e("n", Integer.toString(no[j - 1]));
                size++;
                Log.e("first size",Integer.toString(size));
            }
            else {
                int y = 0, pos = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    if ((rowitems.get(i).title).equals((items.get(j - 1).name))) {
                        y = 1;
                        pos = i;
                    }
                }
                if (y == 1) {
                    Log.e("else j-1",Integer.toString(j-1));
                    no[j - 1] = no[j - 1] + 1;
                    Log.e("else no[j-1]",Integer.toString(no[j-1]));
                    rowitems.get(pos).no =Integer.toString(1+Integer.parseInt(rowitems.get(pos).no));

                   String s= rowitems.get(pos).cost;
                    int c=Integer.parseInt(s);
                    c=c+cos[j-1];
                    Log.e("C", Integer.toString(c));
                    //co[j-1]=c;
                    rowitems.get(pos).cost=Integer.toString(c);
                    Log.e("else co[j-1]", Integer.toString(co[j - 1]));
                    Log.e("else c",Integer.toString(c));
                    Log.e("else size",Integer.toString(size));
                }
                else {
                    Log.e("else else j-1",Integer.toString(j-1));
                    no[j - 1] = no[j - 1] + 1;
                    Log.e("else else no[j-1]",Integer.toString(no[j-1]));
                    list item = new list(items.get(j - 1).colorId, items.get(j - 1).name, Integer.toString(co[j-1]), Integer.toString(no[j - 1]));
                    rowitems.add(item);
                   /* String s=items.get(j-1).cost.toString();
                    int c=Integer.parseInt(s);
                    c=c+(c/no[j-1]);
                    setCost(j-1,Integer.toString(c));
                    MyAdaptertwo.this.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

                    size++;
                    Log.e("else else size",Integer.toString(size));
                }
            }


        }
    });
   Button sub=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.sub);
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (size > 0) {
                Log.e("if size ",Integer.toString(size));
                int y = 0, pos = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                    Log.e("if i ",Integer.toString(i));
                    Log.e("if j-1 ",Integer.toString(j-1));
                    if ((rowitems.get(i).title).equals((items.get(j - 1).name))) {
                        y = 1;
                        pos = i;
                        Log.e("title",rowitems.get(i).title);
                        Log.e("name",items.get(j-1).name);
                        Log.e("if pos ",Integer.toString(pos));
                    }
                }
                if (y == 1) {
                    no[j - 1] = no[j - 1] - 1;
                    Log.e("y==1 no[j-1] ",Integer.toString(no[j-1]));
                    rowitems.get(pos).no = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(rowitems.get(pos).no)-1);
                    Log.e("row no",   rowitems.get(pos).no);
                    String s= rowitems.get(pos).cost;
                    int c=Integer.parseInt(s);
                    c=c-cos[j-1];
                    Log.e("C", Integer.toString(c));
                    //co[j-1]=c;
                    rowitems.get(pos).cost=Integer.toString(c);
                    Log.e("else co[j-1]", Integer.toString(co[j - 1]));
                    Log.e("else c",Integer.toString(c));
                    Log.e("else size",Integer.toString(size));
                    if (no[j - 1] <= 0) {
                        if (size == 1) {
                            size = 0;
                            rowitems.clear();
                        } else if (size > 1) {
                            rowitems.remove(pos);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


        }
    });
    return v;
}


private class Item
{
    final String name;
    final int colorId;
     String cost;
    final int vnId;

    Item(String name, int drawableId,String cost,int vnId)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.colorId = drawableId;
        this.cost=cost;
        this.vnId=vnId;
       }
}
```

}

Xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFF">
<com.food.foodjugaad.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:padding="5dp"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
     />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Rs."
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:id="@+id/rs"
   />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cost"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rs"
    />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
    android:layout_below="@+id/picture"
    android:id="@+id/vnon"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="+"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vnon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cost"
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:background="@drawable/button_back"/>
<Button
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:text="-"
    android:id="@+id/sub"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:layout_below="@+id/vnon"
    android:background="@drawable/button_background"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/add"/>



   </RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat -

```
  Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.042.016 +       62ca4eb + acd831d + 9f8b442 + e027a02 + cba30ba + 53c303a + a649d79 + 23e16f8 + 5e97da7 + cbd2a44 + 33d072a + 7aacf06 + 72b33e7 + 28f6f60 + b4c13d8 +  NOTHING
  12-28 16:24:28.585  15183-15204/com.food.foodjugaad I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
  12-28 16:24:28.607  15183-15204/com.food.foodjugaad D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
   12-28 16:24:34.981  15183-15204/com.food.foodjugaad D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb8017500 (GridView) with handle 0xb80994e0
    12-28 16:24:36.571  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/first j-1﹕ 0
   12-28 16:24:36.571  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/first no[j-1]﹕ 1
    12-28 16:24:36.572  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/n﹕ 1
    12-28 16:24:36.572  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/first size﹕ 1
    12-28 16:24:37.304  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else j-1﹕ 0
   12-28 16:24:37.304  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else no[j-1]﹕ 1
  12-28 16:24:37.304  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/C﹕ 2
    12-28 16:24:37.304  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else co[j-1]﹕ 1
   12-28 16:24:37.304  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else c﹕ 2
    12-28 16:24:37.304  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else size﹕ 1
      12-28 16:24:39.759  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else else j-1﹕ 3
      12-28 16:24:39.759  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else else no[j-1]﹕ 1
     12-28 16:24:39.759  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else else size﹕ 2
      12-28 16:24:41.229  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else else j-1﹕ 2
       12-28 16:24:41.229  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else else no[j-1]﹕ 1
        12-28 16:24:41.229  15183-15183/com.food.foodjugaad E/else else size﹕ 3
        12-28 16:24:42.196  15183-15204/com.food.foodjugaad D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb81a6018 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xb82722f8
```

Comment: before adding to items try `items.clear()` in `MyAdaptertwo()`'s constructor .

Comment: @RRR how will that help?

Comment: try it first, you are adding items to array evrytime

Comment: The list is not repeating but if i click on the last item it is referring to the 2nd last item. For the rest,it is fine. @RRR

Answer (score 4):

You should remove the `static` when you declare your `ArrayList` and also I recommend you to use `private` instead of `public`

```
public static List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

to

```
 private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

The reason is: The static variable belongs to the class, not any particular object of that class. It will not release so every time you create the your `Adapter` the list will keep increase. It is really bad for performance

Hope this help

Comment: The list is not repeating but if i click on the last item it is referring to the 2nd last item. And when i click on the 2nd last item,it referes to the third last. The rest are fine.

Comment: It is there in the code that i have uploaded. The buttons are named add and sub.

Comment: did you write some logcat inside your Button onClick. I see in your code it have no logcat? please write some logcat then show me the log

Comment: please write this log inside your `onClick`:  `Log.e("TAG","click"+i);`

Comment: @TeeKay sorry for late response, if you think my answer solve your problem please mark it as correct answer ;) thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are adding values in `items` everytime. Clear it before adding items to it.

```
items.clear();
```

regarding your `outOfBoundException`

your items will be having 15 values when you run it 3 times but your `no`,`co` and `cos` will not be having 15 values.

If static List is not required removed it, it will solve your all problem. Simply write,

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
```

Comment: The list is not repeating but if i click on the last item it is referring to the 2nd last item. For the rest,it is fine. @RRR

Answer (score 0):

clear your array before adding new values in it.

arrayName.clear();